# Sonar server doesn't start after adding plugin to the extension's directory

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I have coded a plugin to be uploaded in sonarqube and the jar file build was success but as I restart the server after pasting the jar file in the extensions folder of the sonar directory, the server doesn't start and I couldn't understand the reason. I am a beginner and there is not much regarding this issue on the web. Thanks in advance!
The log file says:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.09.30 17:29:54 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.0.1DefaultH2Database\sonarqube-5.0.1\sonarqube-5.0.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu.PERSISTENT\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process8704900145169643062properties
2015.09.30 17:29:55 INFO  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.09.30 17:29:55 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.09.30 17:29:55 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] version[1.1.2], pid[2256], build[e511f7b/2014-05-22T12:27:39Z]
2015.09.30 17:29:55 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] initializing ...
2015.09.30 17:29:55 INFO  sea[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1443614394172] loaded [], sites []
2015.09.30 17:29:56 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] initialized
2015.09.30 17:29:56 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] starting ...
2015.09.30 17:29:57 INFO  sea[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1443614394172] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/10.44.70.245:9001]}
2015.09.30 17:30:00 INFO  sea[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1443614394172] new_master [sonar-1443614394172][x3cgIkgcRVOWfewWs39JHA][PS8931][inet[/10.44.70.245:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1443614394172}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.09.30 17:30:00 INFO  sea[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1443614394172] sonarqube/x3cgIkgcRVOWfewWs39JHA
2015.09.30 17:30:01 INFO  sea[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1443614394172] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
2015.09.30 17:30:01 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] started
2015.09.30 17:30:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.09.30 17:30:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.0.1DefaultH2Database\sonarqube-5.0.1\sonarqube-5.0.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\sonarqube-5.0.1DefaultH2Database\sonarqube-5.0.1\sonarqube-5.0.1\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu.PERSISTENT\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process4652516304025422914properties
2015.09.30 17:30:05 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting web
2015.09.30 17:30:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2015.09.30 17:30:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp]  Webapp directory: D:\sonarqube-5.0.1DefaultH2Database\sonarqube-5.0.1\sonarqube-5.0.1\web
2015.09.30 17:30:06 INFO  web[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1443614394172] loaded [], sites []
2015.09.30 17:30:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 5.0.1 / 2c86ad5a003cfe6db1287a25c35acfa0561300c9
2015.09.30 17:30:07 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2015.09.30 17:30:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: D:\sonarqube-5.0.1DefaultH2Database\sonarqube-5.0.1\sonarqube-5.0.1
2015.09.30 17:30:08 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Install plugins...
2015.09.30 17:30:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Core / 5.0.1 / 2c86ad5a003cfe6db1287a25c35acfa0561300c9
2015.09.30 17:30:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.0.1 / 2c86ad5a003cfe6db1287a25c35acfa0561300c9
2015.09.30 17:30:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.4 / a334be36ba4374bb779255272c53fb08675ac2c2
2015.09.30 17:30:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Java / 3.5 / 5c297217308e256603d5070aace960d3f5f2064b
2015.09.30 17:30:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Git / 5.0.1 / 2c86ad5a003cfe6db1287a25c35acfa0561300c9
2015.09.30 17:30:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin My Sonar plugin / 1.0-SNAPSHOT
2015.09.30 17:30:09 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Plugin sameit needs a more recent version of SonarQube than 5.0.1. At least 5.1 is expected
2015.09.30 17:30:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_60-b27 [Windows 7-amd64]
2015.09.30 17:30:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[jruby.rack]  initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.get(JRubyFacade.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getDatabase(JRubyFacade.java:227) ~[sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:95) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:184) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1156) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1114) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:838) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2727) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:359) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1107) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(RubyKernel.java:1094) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:419) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:396) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsRackApplicationFactory.createApplicationObject(RailsRackApplicationFactory.java:22) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$1.create(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$RackApplicationImpl.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:420) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:111) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.doInit(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:94) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext]  Error listenerStart
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext]  Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015.09.30 17:30:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoader]  The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2015.09.30 17:30:15 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started
2015.09.30 17:30:15 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isReady(EmbeddedTomcat.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isReady(WebServer.java:45) [sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:80) ~[sonar-process-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:65) [sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
2015.09.30 17:30:15 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is stopped
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2015.09.30 17:30:15 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  sea[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] stopping ...
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] stopped
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] closing ...
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1443614394172] closed
2015.09.30 17:30:16 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you had a look at the log of the server ? It could be worthy to actually share it with your question so others can help.

Comment: @benzonico ...sorry about the late reply..here I added the log file content!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all written in your log:

> 2015.09.30 17:30:09 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
>   org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: **Plugin sameit needs a more recent version of SonarQube than 5.0.1. At least 5.1 is expected**

Please consider upgrading your SQ version or upgrade/remove plugin mentioned.

Comment: yeah @benzonico ..I changed the versiona nd it worked fine ..thanks!